# ffmpeg: specify source IP for rtp multicast

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to multicast some video for test and development purposes.  I want to be able to specify the source IP address.  I found out how to do that with a udp:// stream, but I don't see that there is a way to do it with rtp://

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i sample.ts -c copy -f rtp_mpegts -fec prompeg=l=5:d=20  "rtp://239.206.206.206:25555?localaddr=192.168.0.10"`

Is what I tried and tcpdump shows the source IP as one of the other IP addresses on the machine.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtp

I'm probably going about this wrong and there's a different way I'm supposed to achieve this.

For more background, I want to simulate video coming from multiple sources and I want to be able to test SSM, which I can't do if the source IP isn't predictable.

Hope that makes sense

Thanks!

-Dylan